# Cosmos client and versioning of records

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm working on a web api where I need to store all previous versions of a record, so for the Put endpoint, instead of updating an existing record, a new record is created, with the same partition key. This complicates things a lot, and a simple Read method, which should give you the most recently created record becomes:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ReadLatestAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var entityList = new List<T>();

        var query = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>()
           .Where(predicate).AsQueryable();

        using (var iterator = query.ToFeedIterator())
        {
            while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                entityList.AddRange(
                    await iterator.ReadNextAsync());
            }
        }

        return entityList.GroupBy(PartitionKey).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp).First());
    }
```

where PartitionKey is found in the specific repositories, like this for instance:

```
public override Func<Project, object> PartitionKey => (x => x.ProjectId);
```

This has worked okay, up until now when I need to add pagination using continuation tokens and need to excecute the whole `GroupBy(PartitionKey).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp).First())` part as part of the cosmos client query for it to work correctly (if the selection is done after the pagination, each GET request will return a different number of records). But the cosmos client doesn't have support for GroupBy, so I'm kind of lost as to how to do this.

Are there any queries that could do the same thing without having to use GroupBy?
Or should I just handle the whole versioning in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

This does not look scalable. There are a few alternatives.

If you always do an in-partition query for the latest mutation you could create a new item that has a different property such as `"version": "latest"` or something that lets you distinguish it from other data in the logical partition. That way you can pass in the partition key value and the value for version there and get just that record. I don't know if EF supports point reads but if you were using the native Cosmos SDK, you could give id a unique value like "latest" instead of creating a new property, then you could call ReadItemAsync() with that id and partition key value for the most efficient possible in Cosmos DB.

If the data for a logical partition will grow beyond 20GB then you will need a different partition key with higher cardinality. In either case, you then need to use Change Feed on the container then create a materialized view of the data where you upsert the container with the latest value such that you can do efficient single-partition queries (or point reads again) in the second container.